# Tasks + participants: JOIN n..n and divide the result on groups (in 1 query)

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-schema

just a small **introduction**:

1. There are **tasks** (*task* table)
2. There are **users** (*user* table)
3. Users can *participate* in different tasks (*task_has_user* table)
4. Participants are divided on author(-s), doer(-s), checker(-s), etc.

[image: The data is stored in following schema:]

I want to get the list of all tasks with comma-separated participants, like this (array-representation):

```
[
  'title' => 'Example task',
  ...
  'authors' => 'Name1 Surname1, Name2 Surname2',
  'doers' => 'Name3 Surname3',
  'checkers' => 'Name4 Surname4'
]
```

in **one** query.

I think MySQL CONCAT (GROUP_CONCAT, etc.) functions may help me in this problem, but I am not sure if it`s right thing to use here.

Please, help :3

Comment: Have you tried *anything* so far?

Comment: @Siyual Yes, I could get all comma-separated participants using ``GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT_WS(' ', `name`, `surname`) SEPARATOR ', ')``. But how to divide them on authors, doers and checkers? (Depends on role column)

Comment: It would be more helpful to post queries you've tried.

Comment: @Siyal I've stuck on the moment I had mentioned above, so..

    SELECT `idtask`, GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT_WS(' ', `name`, `surname`) SEPARATOR ', ') AS `all_participants`
    FROM `task`
    JOIN `task_has_user` ON `idtask` = `task_idtask`
    JOIN `user` ON `iduser` = `user_iduser`

And it looks like this:

[
  'title' => 'Example task',
  ...
  'all_participants' => 'Name1 Surname1, Name2 Surname2, Name3 Surname3, Name4 Surname4'
]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did it this way in Laravel v4.2.
Number of queries = 6 * number of tasks. Heavy.. but I will change it soon.

```
/**
 * Get the full list of tasks with participants
 * @return array
 */
public static function index() {
  /**
   * All tasks
   * @var array
   */
  $tasks = DB::select("SELECT `title` FROM `task` ");

  /**
   * All roles
   * @var array
   */
  $roles = ['doers', 'checkers', 'authors'];

  foreach ($tasks as &$task)
  {
    foreach ($roles as $role) {
      $sql = "SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT_WS(' ', `name`, `surname`) SEPARATOR ', ') AS `$role` FROM `task` ";
      $sql .= "JOIN `task_has_user` ON `idtask` = `task_idtask` ";
      $sql .= "JOIN `user` ON `iduser` = `user_iduser` ";
      $sql .= "WHERE `task_has_user`.`role` = " . (array_search($role, $roles) + 1);

      $task->$role = DB::select($sql)[0]->$role;
    }
  }

  return $tasks;
}
```